# Skyrim, Console: get list of dead NPC'S? Get command-result into file?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I dug out an old Skyrim-save from the depths of my computer and I was wondering: is there any way via console-commands that would allow me to check which NPC's I killed/let die in that play through?

I have the basic idea figured out (get RefID's of known NPC's, get their health, if it's 0, they are dead.), but I fail at "grab list of Ref-ID's" currently.

Also, can I somehow reroute the result of commands coming from a batch-file into some text-file?

Comment: It should be possible to dump a list of NPCs into a file, and then write a script that checks each NPC to see if they’re alive. [ConScrybe](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/19630/?) could be useful. It lets you save console output to a log file.

Comment: "save funclist 1" is the command to get a text file of all npc's and their ref Id's.

Comment: @amaranth An answer that requires a mod or additional piece of software might get dinged for being a software recommendation.

Comment: @DCShannon Really? People ask “how do I do this in Skyrim” all the time, and half the time, the answer is, “you can’t, without a mod.” I answered something like that yesterday. Is that breaking a guideline somewhere?

Comment: @amaranth I think it's fine myself, but it's clearly better if a mod suggestion is in addition to a way to do it with just the game. It's more a problem for questions than for answers, but the way logic works around here sometimes, people will conclude that the question is asking for software if the only answers only suggest software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't dump it to a file, but you could just go to the dead body cleanup cell with 'coc WIDeadBodyCleanupCell' in the console and have a look around.